# Can I launch Graphical applications inside Ubuntu server or any Linux server?

Tags: server, gui

Consider this scenario, I have installed Ubuntu server in my computer. Can I launch any graphical application like Android-studio or Mozilla firefox from the OS? 
To be more specific if I navigate to the folder which has the application,
and type `chmod +x myapp.sh` and then type `sh ./ myapp.sh` . .. what is going to happen?

I am just Curious to know

Comment: I think not. First of all, to install them, you need to install all their dependency packages, which includes all the graphical libraries from e.g. X11 and whatnot. Second, these applications need to connect to a running display server to start, which again requires you to have a graphical environment ready and running. Maybe you can cheat a bit here or there, but I don't think it is possible. Anyway, what would you want to do with a running GUI application without a GUI?

Comment: @ByteCommander thanks. That explains my doubt. Normally you wouldnt want to do it, I asked this out of curiosity. Thanks